# Python 2.7 counting number of strings

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to count the number of times in a list a string has more than 20 characters.

I am trying to use the count method and this is what I keep getting:

```
>>> for line in lines:
        x = len(line) > 20
        print line.count(x)
```

edit: sorry for the indentation mistake before

Comment: you have incorrect indentation as well as code.

Comment: Where have you seen the `.count` method used like this? `str.count(x)` return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of `x`. Here your `x` is either `True` or `False` ie. not even a str. Which is why you get that error message.

Comment: How about using `len(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 20, lines))`?

Comment: I was under the impression the count method counted overlapping occurrences. Thank you for pointing out this was not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
>>> s = ['sdgsdgdsgjhsdgjgsdjsdgjsd', 'ads', 'dashkahdkdahkadhaddaad']
>>> cnt = 0
>>> for i in s:
        if len(i) > 20:
            cnt += 1


>>> cnt
2
```

or

```
>>> sum(1 if len(i) > 20 else 0 for i in s)
2
```

or

```
>>> sum(len(i) > 20 for i in s)
2
```

Comment: Or just `cnt = sum(len(i) > 20 for i in s)` ?

Comment: @JonClements i'm the first.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

```
x = len(line) > 20
```

x is a boolean, which cannot be "counted" in a string.

```
>>> 'a'.count(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

You need to actually have a string or similar type (Unicode, etc.) to be counted in the line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a simple counter for your purpose:

```
count = 0
for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 20:
        count += 1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     x = len(line) > 20
```

here, `x` is a boolean type (`True` or `False` in Python), because  `len(line) > 20` is a logic expression.

You may figure out the problem by debugging:

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     x = len(line) > 20
...     print x
```

Besides, `x = len(line) > 20` is not a condition expression. You need to use `if` expression:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for line in lines:    
...     if len(line) > 20:
...         count += 1    
... 
>>> print count
```